# TikZ, standalone and circuite.ee.IEC, strange bounding box

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, tikz-circuit-lib

I'm using `standalone` to create PDF output of a `tikzpicture`.  But I run into a problem when I use the circuit library.
Here's a mwe that shows that simply adding the line `\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}` throws off the boundary of the resulting PDF file.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (10,10);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which (on my machine) produces the following PDF (note the huge amount of whitespace to the left of (0,0), the bottom left corner of the grid).

Any help appreciated!
[image]

Comment: You should load the TikZ libraries in the preamble, i.e. place `\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}` before `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
```